# Extending opencv/find_obj.cpp to recognize multiple objects

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, webcam, surf

I'm really new to OpenCV, so please bear with me.

I've managed to modify the find_obj.cpp example to use a webcam/live-video-feed rather than the "scene_filename" argument.

In this way, when I invoke the example, I give it one image as my object to be detected.
The video feed then looks at a scene for that "object".

To my surprise, this extend-example works very well. I'd like to extend it to recognize multiple objects, however I'm not sure how to go about this.

These "multiple objects" would be various image files in a directory.

Can anyone give me any suggestions and/or hints on how I might approach such a problem?

At this point, since this is a learning exercise, I'm not looking for speed or performance, but rather just understanding how this would work.

BTW my development is taking place on a Linux/Ubuntu platform and I'm using C/C++ (though I'm comfortable with python as well.)

Comment: Unless you want us to get naked with you, it's "bear with me", not "bare with me".